# Trying to get a HashCode for a simple list of custom POCO's

Tags: c#, .net, hashcode

I'm trying to create a simple HashCode of a list of weather results (custom POCO's) and would like to know if what I'm doing is ok/fine.

I have a time based process that checks the weather results for a 5 locations. I store each weather result in a List:

```
{
  "results": [
    {
      "Id": 1,
      "Location": "New York City",
      "Temp": "21.7",
      "Metric": "Celsius"
    },
    {
      "Id": 2,
      "Location": "San Francisco",
      "Temp": "18.1",
      "Metric": "Celsius"
    },
    ....
    {
      "Id": 5,
      "Location": "Melbourne",
      "Temp": "33.1",
      "Metric": "Celsius"
    }
  ]
}
```

So I wish to get a HashCode / unique fingerprint .. store this in a db. Later on, I'll grab the latest weather results again ... and this time compare this most recent result against the previous result (in the db).

To do this, I'm doing the following:

```
private static string ToHash(IEnumerable<Weather> weatherResults)
{
    byte[] hash;

    // MD5 or SHA256?
    using (var algorithm = MD5.Create())
    {
        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(weatherResults);
        hash = algorithm.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json));
    }

    return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(hash);
}
```

1. So i'm using `MD5` because I don't care about security (eg. this isn't passwords we're storing) and would like this to be fast.
2. I'm converting the list to JSON as an easy way to get a standard text representation of my weather list. (simple serialization)

When I do the code (above) I get some weird text results ... here's a snapshot:

[image]

So the code seems to generate some textual representation of my lists. I can store this text into the db.

So it feels like, what I'm doing is ok -> I would just like someone to confirm if the steps I'm doing are fine.

Answer (score 2):

> When I do the code (above) I get some weird text results

That's because you're treating *arbitrary binary data* (a cryptographic hash) as if it's UTF-8-encoded text data. It's like trying to open a JPG file in Notepad - you'll see garbage, because a JPG file isn't a text file.

If you want printable text, you should convert to hex or base64. Base64 is probably the simplest:

```
return Convert.ToBase64String(hash);
```

Note that if you put the return statement inside the `using` statement you don't even need the extra local variable:

```
private static string ToHash(IEnumerable<Weather> weatherResults)
{
    using (var algorithm = MD5.Create())
    {
        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(weatherResults);
        var hash = algorithm.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json));
        return Convert.ToBase64String(hash);
    }
}
```

This personally feels somewhat brittle though - it's relying on the *precise* JSON representation of the POCO. In particular, if you were to change some aspect of serialization, e.g. changing the field names in the JSON, then the hash would change even if the data didn't, which may not be what you want. As another example, suppose you add an `int` field to your POCO - the JSON representation of all your *existing* data would change to include that value even if it's 0, so all the hashes would change.

(It's also quite an inefficient way of hashing data, but that may well not be important.)

This *may* all be fine for you, but you need to consider your requirements as your data type evolves.

Comment: Thank you Jon for your thoughts and suggestions. Given the warnings, I'm not sure what other options I should consider? For example, serializing as JSON is brittle (fields change, serialization format changes, etc) ... so instead of JSON ... what else could I use? Secondly, you said that this is an inefficient way of hashing. What other suggestions would you suggest for a more efficient way. Security is not an issue (it's not a password). Again - thank you again for you help!

Comment: @Pure.Krome: I can't really offer an answer without knowing more requirements - that's the thing you need to think about. How do you expect the data model to evolve, and how does that affect how you use the hashes? (For example, if you're happy to rehash the data if the model changes, that may be fine.) How important is performance? Lots of questions to think about - and I'm not inviting answers in comments here; once you've thought about this carefully, it may be worth asking a new question with all the details.